# Universal Analytics Not Giving Me Updated Code

Tags: google-analytics

My job is to upgrade the current analytics to universal analytics. Hunting around, I could not find that annoying universal analytics upgrade notification in the property settings. Checking the documentation, I can confirm that this platform was already on UA!

I head over to "Tracking Info" (not "Tracking Code" as the old one used to be), and it says UA-123456-1 with the classic tracking code.

Problems: The tracking code is classic and not universal. I have no idea to confirm that its universal or classic.

Completely confused on what's going on inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Ben**, not sure if all of the accounts were offered the upgrade -- maybe you are still on the waiting list:

> The option to upgrade Universal Analytics will roll out to standard
>   accounts. Once this option is available in your account, it will
>   appear in the Admin section.

Also, keep in mind that if you are using Retargeting (dc.js) -- it is not supported by Universal Analytics as of yet and those account should not upgrade:

> Universal Analytics does not currently support the the dc.js
>   JavaScript and related features (Remarketing, Google Display Network
>   Impression Reporting, DoubleClick Campaign Manager Integration, and
>   the Google Analytics Demographics and Interests Reports). If you use
>   any of these features, upgrade to Universal Analytics after dc.js is
>   supported.

All needed information should be available in the [Analytics Upgrade Center](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/), check it out...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is turned on: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=en&utm_id=ad

Comment: If I turn this off, will I be allowed to upgrade?

Comment: Turned it off just in case. I'd rather have UA than DC.

Comment: Sure, they will make it available once UA is out of beta anyway. Not sure what is the policy though on making the upgrade available...